# Selecting nodes with non-ASCII characters in Scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, character-encoding, web-scraping, scrapy

I have the following simple web scraper written in `Scrapy`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class MySpiderTest(BaseSpider):
    name = 'MySpiderTest'
    allowed_domains = ["boliga.dk"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.boliga.dk/bbrinfo/3B71489C-AEA0-44CA-A0B2-7BD909B35618",]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = bbrItem()
        print hxs.select("id('unitControl')/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[td//text()[contains(.,'Antal Badeværelser')]]/td[2]/text()").extract()
```

but when I run the spider I get the following syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe6' in file... on line 32, but no encoding declared
```

because of the `æ` in the `xpath`. The xpath is working in `Xpath Checker` for `Firefox`. I tried URL-encoding the `æ`, but that didn't work. What am I missing?

thanks!

**UPDATE:** I have added the encoding declaration in the beginning of the code (Latin-1 should support Danish characters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a unicode string for your XPath expression

```
hxs.select(u"id('unitControl')/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[td//text()[contains(.,'Antal Badeværelser')]]/td[2]/text()").extract()
```

or

```
hxs.select(u"id('unitControl')/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[td//text()[contains(.,'Antal Badev\u00e6relser')]]/td[2]/text()").extract()
```

See [Unicode Literals in Python Source Code](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I still get the error with your solution.

Comment: I looked at the link you posted and added `#!/usr/bin/env python` and
`# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-` to the start of the file, but it still returns the same error.

Comment: Now it works, thanks!! I corrected in the wrong spider :( sorry

Comment: Interestingly, to me at least, I only the second solution returns the right value `[u'2']`. The first solution returns an empty list `[]`. Any thoughts on why?

Comment: ah yeah, the first solution would require a `# -*- coding: ` line in your source file, and depends on it's real encoding, for example I only work in UTF8 and generally add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: @pault. please check my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102025/scrapy-on-arabic-letters-returns-something-strange

Answer (score 0):

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character ‘\xe2′ in file … on line 40,
```

but no decoding declared …

This is caused by the **replacing** standard characters like **apostrophe** (‘) by non-standard characters like **quotation** mark (`) during copying.

Try to edit the text copied from pdf.

Answer (score 0):

```
repsonse.xpath("//tr[contains(., '" + u'中文字符' + "')]").extract()
```