# Scrapy on arabic letters returns something strange

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I am  using `scrapy` on arabic letters and english letters.

The english letters work perfectly.

However, the arabic letters shows like this:

```
gs300 2006  \u0644\u0643\u0632\u0633 \u062c\u064a
```

Any help, please? I am using python with scrapy 0.20.2.

The way i extract data is:

```
site.xpath('my selector').extract()
```

and I call the json operation from cmd like this

```
scrapy crawl dmoz -o items.json -t json
```

Answer (score 3):

The strings `\u0000` are Unicode code points. Each represents a single character (e.g. `\u064a` represents [yeh](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/064a/index.htm)). To convert these characters into something more useful, you will have to use [`encode` and `decode`](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) to handle Unicode strings properly.

Comment: I am not printing data here. I am just extracting and the return the result. so i guess there is nothign on code i cad do , right? i think there is something from the cmd when i write the json. i am just thinking , correct me please

Comment: `\u` + four-hex-digits is the correct way of encoding Unicode codepoints representing non-ASCII characters (see http://www.json.org/ ). So when asking Scrapy to export items in JSON format, seeing "gs300 2006  \u0644\u0643\u0632\u0633 \u062c\u064a" in `items.json` is perfectly normal and expected. I guess all depends on how you use `items.json` after the Scrapy phase. But all JSON compliant reader/decoder should be fine with this kind of input. How are you reading `items.json` and what is your issue with it?

Comment: @pault. do you imply that I am extracting the json good. I just need to know how to read it? i read it by using notepad ++. it is a test editor. what should I do please?

Comment: @pault. kindly your help please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143629/python-scrapy-save-arabic-content-to-json-file

Comment: It really depends on how you want to use the data after the Scrapy step. If it's with Python, you're good with this JSON data. Othrewise, you can consider exporting the items in CSV (and the file will use UTF8 encoding I think)